# Oracle APEX 5.0 dynamically embedding PDF into page

Tags: javascript, oracle, pdf, embed, oracle-apex-5

hello APEX beginner here,

I'm having trouble dynamically embedding pdf url's into my application. Images show up normally, but it does not work with pdf's.

I have an apex_process to call a procedure used to download BLOB files(*code1). This apex_process is called through an URL. I've gotten img tags to show images whenever I set the said url in the img tag's src property.
   However, this does not seem to work with object tags. Setting the url of an object tag's data property does nothing.

Does anyone know how to dynamically show pdf's stored in the DB. 
any help is appreciated

APEX 5.0.4
Oracle 11g

*code1

```
sys.htp.init;
sys.htp.p('Content-length: ' || sys.dbms_lob.getlength(p_FileBlob));
sys.htp.p('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || p_FileNm|| '"' );
sys.owa_util.http_header_close;
sys.wpg_docload.download_file(p_FileBlob);
```

update

I may have been unclear on my objective. I want to actually embed a pdf into my page, like have an adobe-reader-esque view directly on the page. Not have a link to download the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a page (page 32) to handle all downloads. It has a hidden ID item (P32_ID) and several before header page processes. Each process handles a different request.

For a pdf it could be as follows:

From the calling page:
f?p=&APP_ID.:32:&SESSION.:GETPDF:NO::P32_ID:YOUR_PDF_ID

What is send to the page is a request: GETPDF and the ID of the PDF to be downloaded.

Page 32 has a ON LOAD - before header page process with a condition REQUEST = Expression 1, GETPDF.

The PLSQL code for this process is:

```
declare
   l_length       pls_integer;
   l_blob         blob;
   l_content_type varchar2(100);
   l_filename     varchar2(30);
begin

   select blobdata
   into l_blob
   from your_blob_table 
   where ID = v('P32_ID');


   l_content_type := 'application/pdf';

   l_length := nvl(dbms_lob.getlength(l_blob), 0);

   if l_length = 0
   then
      htp.p('No data');
      return;
   end if;

   l_filename := 'GETPDF.pdf';


   -- create response header
   owa_util.mime_header(l_content_type, false);
   -- add furhter header attributes
   htp.p('Content-length: ' || l_length);
   htp.p('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || l_filename || '"');
   -- close the headers
   owa_util.http_header_close;
   -- download the BLOB
   wpg_docload.download_file(l_blob);

exception
   when others then
      htp.p(sqlerrm);
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

Content-Disposition: inline;

It's the key

Comment: Please make a habit to explain your solution. Good explanation helps any future reader why and how your solution worked.